# How to show select field with pre-selected data using django forms?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I've a django Form with 2 choices (yes and no), on my "create page" i can render the `select` field to save the data and it works just fine, when i try to use on the "edit page" the value is not pre-selected with the current value, how can i make the current value `selected` on the `select` input field?

The form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    choose = forms.BooleanField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Select(
            choices=[(1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No')],
            attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

When i call the view to edit:

```
class MyUpdateView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    SuccessMessageMixin,
    UpdateView,
):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name = "my/template.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my-url')
    success_message = 'Updated!'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        data = super(MyUpdateView, self).get_object()
        if not data.user == self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        
        # data.choose is False

        return data
```

The `HTML` input will be always "1" (Yes) even tough the current value is "0" (No)

The HTML:

```
{{ form.choose }}
```

The Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    choose = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        verbose_name='Cumulativo'
    )
```

Comment: You've not included `BenefitForm` but that's used for the edit by the looks of things. Does that do anything with initial data or field values? Have you confirmed the value on the instance when it's loaded into the form?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `MyUpdateView`:

```
initial = { 'choose': 1 }
```

Comment: The problem is not the initial value is that the form needs to use the value coming from the model :)
if the model contains "1" the selected value should be "yes" otherwise "no"

Comment: I see, can you please post your model?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the custom field 'choose' in the form, which does not refer to MyModel field 'choose'. that's why you are always getting the first value 'Y' as default or the first value 'Y' in the dropdown.

If you want to refer to your model object, you can simply use self keyword in the form

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choose'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo, i'm already using the `MyModel` on the form class and the `MyForm` on my UpdateView class

Comment: Yes, you are right about the fact that you are using MyModel in your form class. But you are creating new field 'choose' in your form class which does not refer to your model class. So, the field which is showing up in your template is your custom field 'choose'. that is not your model field in the form.